# Twitter typeahead.js / bloodhound.js with XML source

Tags: twitter-typeahead, bloodhound

Is it possible to construct a typeahead.js / bloodhound.js (or similar) search that is XML (not JSON) based?  I have a large XML document in memory already, and I'd hate to make another copy of it to accommodate JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can write a custom search handler that bypasses Bloodhound by setting a function in the `source` parameter as is shone here: http://www.ur-ban.com/2015/08/04/using-typeahead-js-without-bloodhound/

Comment: Could you explain this a bit more? As I'm trying to use an external XML file as my source, but I keep getting origin error messages. Plus, the example you linked to above doens't seem to work for me. What info do you need?